# System.Threading.Timer time issue

Tags: c#, .net, time, timer, intervals

I have an issue with Threading.Timer in my .NET application.
To make it easier to understand I made a sample.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace TimerTestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Timer timer;
        private static int timerTickCounter;
        private static DateTime timerStartTimer;
        private static readonly Stopwatch Sw = new Stopwatch();
        private static readonly ManualResetEvent TimerFinish = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("START");
            timer = new Timer(TimerCallBack, null, 0, 1000);
            TimerFinish.WaitOne();
        }

        private static void TimerCallBack(object state)
        {
            if (timerTickCounter == 0)
            {
                timerStartTimer = DateTime.Now;
                Sw.Start();
            }
            timerTickCounter++;
            Console.WriteLine("timerTickCounter = {0}", timerTickCounter);
            if (timerTickCounter >= 1200) //20.00 min
            {
                var secondsSinceStart = (int)(DateTime.Now - timerStartTimer).TotalSeconds;
                timer.Dispose();
                Sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("timerTickCounter = {0}; secondsSinceStart={1}; Stowatchseconds={2}",
                                    timerTickCounter, secondsSinceStart, Sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                Console.ReadLine();
                TimerFinish.Set();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After running this code I have the very last line with resut:

`timerTickCounter = 1200; secondsSinceStart=1215; Stowatchseconds=1215,7573291`

As far as you can see timer ticks each second, but the resulting output says it took 15 seconds more time for program to run.

I need mechanism to update `DateTime` fields, and I cannot simply create a timer which ticks once a second.

Can anyone propose a solution for this?

Comment: Approach it from the other side. How much accuracy do you actually need? Do you have a calibration point?

Comment: I need an exact accuracy if it is correct to say so. No, I don't have a calibration point.

Answer (score 1):

All Timers operate with a ~20ms resolution. So 15 seconds on 20 minutes is inside the expected range.

If you really need a very accurate 1/second timer than you'll need to use a one-shot timer and calculate the remainder of the second each time.

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain it, i don't get it. You mean I need to remember DateTime.Now on each tick and calculate (Now - PrevTime)?

Comment: Yes. You need to resync, once per hour/minute/second. DateTime.Now is your only fixed reference point.

Comment: Now i got it. Thanks. Never thought that such simple operation will take so much efforts.